# How can I convert a nested set model tree hierarchy to into HTML list elements with PHP?

Tags: php, database, sql

I have a hierarchical tree stored in a database using the nested set model. How can I print this hierarchy in a `<li>` list with PHP?

my database table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfhpW.png

my tree structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTRJK.png

Comment: show your table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to recursion try this code or php

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("testing_db", $con);

$code_id = 1; // initial of hierarchy // you can put here 1/2/3 as your initial node
print_hierarchy($code_id);

function print_hierarchy($code_id)
{
    echo '<ul>';
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test2` WHERE id='$code_id' LIMIT 1 ") or die(mysql_error());
    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {

        $left = $row['lft'];
        $right = $row['rgt'];
        echo '<li>'.$row['name'];
        if($left>0 && $left!=$code_id)
        {
            print_hierarchy($left);
        }
        if($right>0 && $right!=$code_id)
        {
            print_hierarchy($right);
        }
        echo '</li>';

    }
    echo '</ul>';   
    return;
}
```

**NOTE :** here i am using `mysql_*` which is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`

Comment: this is tested try it with your table and fields name

Comment: in your code you use mysql_query() function, but you dont specify the mysql connection, it would be nice to include that in your code, maybe someone else doesn't know this and wonders why it isn't working

Comment: When i use $code_id = 1 i get: `*organism`, 
when i use $code_id = 2 i get: `*mammals` and then indented `*peacock`
when i use $code_id = 3 i get: `*human` and then indented `*birds`

Comment: Here is a diagram showing the output for $code_id = 1/2/3
http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUjAS.png

Comment: this is left drawn tree in ul li if you want to downline hierarchical you need some plug in and use above code.

Comment: but the it is totaly mixed up because it displays `peacock` under `mammals` and `human` under `birds`

Is it possible that i have assinged my lft and rgt values incorrectly?

Comment: how you relate them please explain

Comment: Running multiple queries is the opposite reason you implement a nested set.